# How do I get noticed on this site?

Tags: discussion

I am new to stack exchange in general and I would like to know how to get noticed more as I seems to not receive many up votes to my posts.

Please give me some good advice on how to do so.

Comment: One reason you aren't getting answers is because you have a **0% Accept Rate**. This means that when people *do* [provide](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46098/what-are-the-differences-between-the-mw3-pistolsp99-and-the-five-seven) [detailed](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46096/how-do-i-get-the-mythic-horse) [answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44872/how-is-the-difference-in-cpt-price-looks-from-mw1-and-mw2-different) [to your questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44878/why-did-niko-bellic-join-the-army), you don't acknowledge them.

Comment: (For reference, to mark an answer as accepted, click on the **Check mark** next to it. This awards reputation both to you, and to the person providing the answer, and is one of the keys to making Stack Exchange work.)

Comment: you have 26 rep...

Comment: fyi politeness counts, hopefully your question will now receive some upvotes :P

Answer (score 18):

You may wish to consult the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), and specifically review [How to Ask Questions.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)  This site is weird - people tend to think of it like a forum, and it really is not like forums at all.

High quality questions are well written, broadly applicable, and are well researched.  They should be focused, and the answer you're looking for should be clear.

If someone reads your question and doesn't understand how to give it a specific answer, they may ask in a comment for you to clarify what you're asking for.  This is important feedback to you, so that you can understand what's missing from your question and how to provide it.

Proper grammar and spelling are important, because this site is about communicating information.  You, as the asker, are communicating what you are asking as clearly as possible so that other people, who are answering, can clearly communicate the correct answer.

Once a question has an answer, (in most cases) it should be clear to everyone who reads the question and the answer that the answer is correct and complete.  If there's no way to do this (ie, a question where you ask "is this console better or is that console better?" where there are multiple or no right answers), that's one indication of a bad question.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some links to some excellent answers on this site.  Granted no one's expecting you to write a dissertation just to answer a simple question, but it shows that being able to back up your answer with hard facts (i.e. testing in game), and sources helps out.  As well as explaining why you think your answer is good.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/21286
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/22291
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/958
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5001
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44599 <---- this one deserves a lot more votes
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46868 <---- same with this one
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/363
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/891
(ok, 3 tzenes example posts are enough, even though he's written so many good ones.)

Also, [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/what-makes-a-question-good) (along with agent86's answer) will give you some pointers in how to ask a better question.

Comment: It should be noted that the OP has more trouble with his questions *not getting* good answers, (or answers at all), than with answering questions effectively himself. The problem there of course, is that he's mostly asking pretty bad questions. :/

Comment: hmm.... that is true.

Comment: Well it always says,Please login or register to favorite this post and I was logged in at first anyway!