# Is flagging and downvoting done in good faith, or is it merely a fun way for "in" members to exercise power?

Tags: discussion, voting

[I asked a question about certain game assets.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310906/what-is-the-difference-between-the-loz-songs-lost-woods-and-sarias-song) These assets happened to be music, but that is kind of beside the point - the question depended on whether there is an in-game or development process related explanation for a seemingly inexplicable anomaly of this content.

Of course, this is my first post on this stack exchange (if not the entire family of websites), so something *must* be wrong enough to get my terrible submission off the front page.

The leading (and only reason) why it is off topic? "it is about music comparison, not gaming". I addressed this in a comment, so I won't bother to again.

Let's looks at it from a broader perspective, and start with the help centers definition of good topics to ask about.

> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including
>   consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question
>   generally covers things such as …
>
> Gameplay strategies and tactics
>   Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
>   Game mechanics and terminology
>   Plot and characters in games
>   Game-specific hardware and utilities
>   …then you are in the right place to ask your question!

My question was in particular a question about terminology specific to a game franchise. Additionally, the narrative reasons for the weird split in terms that prompted my question are.... plot and characters in games.

Let's look at the other side, the stuff it says you shouldn't do. I won't even bother to list the category, as there is only one possible red flag:

> Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative

Not only is this not the issue that my question was closed for, as the quick and relevant answer proved, it's not really a question with a speculative answer. There is a relatively definitive answer based on how the story works and how the music relates to that.

Furthermore, my question clearly triggers none of the red flags for "subjective questions" that users are to be wary of. It also generally fulfills all *9 listed qualities of a good question* in a [post that has been updated this year](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/what-makes-a-question-good).

What has been accomplished here? A question was asked about material in videogames and they're relation to each other. I could not think of a more appropriate place to ask a question about videogames. This was not a music question - no where was there the implication that a musical analysis was necessary, just an analysis in the context of the game.

Someone answered the question with a good answer and fulfilled my curiosity. Everything seemed to work as it should, besides 1 person misinterpreting it - or not bothering to even read it, seeing that I was a new user - which triggered a pile-on of people who echoed this users flag/vote without responding to my rebuttal or leaving any comment regarding the matter.

Why would any individual come here to ask a question if they knew they would be treated poorly so someone could get the thrill of flagging and downvoting? I got an answer, I guess. I probably could have gotten that anywhere.

If questions from new users are going to be automatically assumed to be poor quality and off topic, for whatever reason, new users won't bother asking here. I thought it would be good to probe the knowledge of an assumed knowledgeable community, but why will I, or an increasing number of potential users, bother with it, knowing that a question is mostly an opportunity to exercise arbitrary internet authority?

Enjoy trolling me in the comments, I guess, I won't be reading them. Have fun with that and the minecraft questions that appear to make up about 50% of the frontpage.

Comment: i'm down voting because of the premise of this question being that it assume malice of downvoters and close voters. it would have been better if you had worded this question asking maybe why it was received so negatively received so that it would be constructive rather than a rant as indicated by your last paragraph where you indicate no interest of reading any replies

Comment: I'm voting to close because the user has proclaimed we should enjoy trolling them in the comments and "(they)won't be reading them". There's no point to this question now.

Comment: Note that users are free to vote (and flag) as they wish. Higher reputation users have (generally) proven themselves to be productive members.  Some users have stricter personal guidelines for what they consider to be acceptable content here, but that's part of what makes community moderation work. You are absolutely free to engage in a discussion if you think something has been done wrong as well, so thank you for coming to meta! If you had worded this post a little less ranty you may have had more success. I personally feel your post is fine, but worded a little confusingly. Perhaps an edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I asked a question about certain game assets.

Sure did, nothing wrong with your question IMO

> Of course, this is my first post on this stack exchange (if not the
>   entire family of websites), so something must be wrong enough to get
>   my terrible submission off the front page.

It isn't off the front page. It's on hold because some users decided it wasn't about video games per our rules. There are also users who agreed with your comment about how your question is valid. We often have discussions here about what is on and off topic.

> Furthermore, my question clearly triggers none of the red flags for
>   "subjective questions" that users are to be wary of. It also generally
>   fulfills all 9 listed qualities of a good question in a post that has
>   been updated this year.

I also agree with you here. I am a fan of fringe questions that are more in-depth than just "how do I collect this weapon" or whatever. I think they are most interesting and thought-provoking. I am also in the minority, and I can't change the rules. I can only try to use what resources I have to make this site better.

> What has been accomplished here? A question was asked about material
>   in videogames and they're relation to each other. I could not think of
>   a more appropriate place to ask a question about videogames. This was
>   not a music question - no where was there the implication that a
>   musical analysis was necessary, just an analysis in the context of the
>   game.

What was accomplished was a vote by users of certain grade who deemed your question off topic. It can also be reopened because even the best users make mistakes.

> Why would any individual come here to ask a question if they knew they
>   would be treated poorly so someone could get the thrill of flagging
>   and downvoting? I got an answer, I guess. I probably could have gotten
>   that anywhere.

I don't believe you were treated poorly. No one gets thrills of flagging questions and downvoting. Downvotes are used to express dislike for a question for numerous reasons, not because you are new or they don't like you. There are hundreds of posts on all of the stack networks explaining this process.

> If questions from new users are going to be automatically assumed to
>   be poor quality and off topic, for whatever reason, new users won't
>   bother asking here. I thought it would be good to probe the knowledge
>   of an assumed knowledgeable community, but why will I, or an
>   increasing number of potential users, bother with it, knowing that a
>   question is mostly an opportunity to exercise arbitrary internet
>   authority?

Questions from new users are not assumed to be poor quality. You have spelling mistakes, poor grammar and a fringe-topic question. That's why you got downvotes. Your post was deemed off-topic because some people don't like questions about video game assets here. You have the opportunity to make a meta post explaining yourself to the community and possibly make a change, but instead you wrote the following paragraph...

> Enjoy trolling me in the comments, I guess, I won't be reading them.
>   Have fun with that and the minecraft questions that appear to make up
>   about 50% of the frontpage.

Again, we're not here to troll you. Don't react this way every time something doesn't go your way. I actually came to the meta section to see if you were going to make a post about your question but I found that this post is filled with malice and angst, instead of trying to learn about the process and what happened.

Comment: You're right, my reaction at the end was unnecessary. However, that one paragraph doesn't suddenly negate the rest of the post -  which was written with all the passion of someone disambiguating a rulebook.

> You have spelling mistakes, poor grammar and a fringe-topic question
What spelling mistakes? What poor grammar? [Are you referring to me using a preposition to end a sentence?](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition)

Comment: It is obvious that my question is plainly readable English, and any ambiguities were answered by my response and further edits. If there is some mechanical error, isn't that the purpose of the wiki-like editing capabilities? Disregarding any schoolyard behavior, the only purpose to flag it at that point is because of a personal disinterest in the question. Which is subjective and clearly not shared among all users - so the answer provided and the question itself is useful.

Comment: The first point I made was that I didn't think there was anything wrong with your question. I love questions like yours. Unfortunately, the rules and regulations of this site are not maintained by only me. I, like everyone else, have to obey the rules. Just because we think the question is valid, doesn't mean 5 other users will think the same. We've had discussion after discussion about off-topic things and sometimes it changes and sometimes it doesn't. I think for the most part we are all trying our best to make this site the best it can be.

Comment: The issue with your meta post is that it doesn't ask "Why was my post closed" and go into the reasons it could have been closed. Instead, it talks about a bias against new users and accuses mods of abusing power. While you can certainly point out times in which that has happened in the past, a lot of the mods on this site are well versed in the site rules and regulations and I personally have never had an issue. I also never have had a situation where a question was closed because of a personal bias or abuse of power.

Comment: I am sorry that I accused those actions as a conscious abuse of power for personal benefit. That was a poor way to frame it, and when I wrote my post I was in an unnecessarily vindictive mood, despite my earlier claims. I realize that this is the groove SE sites settle down into sometimes, but I was just disappointed to see that my meticulously rules-conforming and interesting (to at least some) question was rejected on
reasons I could specifically prove baseless. I was hopeful for a "better" alternative to all the other adjacent sites out there, and when my hopes were dashed I was upset.

Comment: @Rick On behalf of everyone here, I accept your apology. I've seen a lot of people come here expecting to be able to ask any question they want and their hopes get crushed, just as you described. I know it took me a while to get used to the rules. It's clear today your mood is different than when this post was made. Hopefully both sides will be able to learn from this and make Arqade even better.

Comment: While Rick didn't phrase this question particularly well, I think many would agree that his original question was ta reasonable, indeed even good one for this site. I've seen other instances here where a less usual question got heavily and incorrectly downvoted just after posting, only to recover later as the collective users came to their senses. There are other SEs that have far stricter question guidelines, but they don't get the kind of immediate downvotes that less usual but good questions get here. So I understand his frustration, though I have no idea how to improve this situation.